# How to verify buttons which are like images

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, calabash, calabash-android

when i give a query in terminal like
    query "* id:'btn_addRemove'"

Then i am getting an output like

```
    [0] {
                        "id" => "btn_addRemove",
                   "enabled" => true,
        "contentDescription" => nil,
                     "class" => "android.widget.ImageView",
                      "rect" => {
            "center_y" => 353,
            "center_x" => 622,
              "height" => 120,
                   "y" => 293,
               "width" => 140,
                   "x" => 552
        },
                       "tag" => nil,
               "description" => "android.widget.ImageView{4307ec68 V.ED..C. ........ 552,35-692,155 #7f06006e app:id/btn_addRemove}"
    },
    [1] {
                        "id" => "btn_addRemove",
                   "enabled" => true,
        "contentDescription" => nil,
                     "class" => "android.widget.ImageView",
                      "rect" => {
            "center_y" => 559,
            "center_x" => 622,
              "height" => 120,
                   "y" => 499,
               "width" => 140,
                   "x" => 552
        },
                       "tag" => nil,
               "description" => "android.widget.ImageView{430557b8 V.ED..C. ........ 552,35-692,155 #7f06006e app:id/btn_addRemove}"
    },
```

Now problem is the "id" is same for both the buttons and when i click on the button , then it will change to green with some image in it and when i click again, the buttton changed to normal one which shows before.

How do i verify this ?

Comment: Hi Lucan, I am not sure I understand you question. So to be sure. You have a number of buttons that have the same id. And you want to be able to manipulate the buttons individually as well as check what state they are in? Is there any reason why they have the same id?

Comment: Hi Lasse, I don't know the reason behind the ids but it is same for both and also i can't get the state from the app like "isSelected" or similar.

Comment: Personally, I'd try to find out why you're getting two objects with the same id, and sort that out. You shouldn't have more than one instance of an id on the page. Only if I was unable to find a way to correct that, would I start looking at how to grab one of the duplicate ids.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple element with same IDs.

Then you can click or verify element using index.

```
query("ImageView css:'#'btn_addRemove'")[0]
```

Let me know, if you issue get resolved.